# using cookieStore over global var

Tags: angularjs

I gather that the cookieStore helps us to store (key value) pairs in the cookies, thereby aiding in the session information storage.

Is it not better to maintain global variables for the same ?

The only reason we would want to using cookie would be to maintain persistent logins. Any other reason ?

Comment: Don't really understand what the question is ..? Yes cookie is usefull to persist data with a potential expicacy. There is also  localstorage/sessionstorage/websql.

Comment: Use cookies when you want to persist something that you want maintained on page refresh. You can use it for anything you like.

Comment: The question is that the cookie enables us to store info. This info is global and this can be achieved with the usage of global vars. So the only condition when the chookie must be used should be when we need to persist the data after the browser/tab close or a page refresh. RIGHT ?